# Sencha Touch 2: List does not display in Panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am working on an MVC app in Sencha Touch 2 and am having trouble getting a list to display in a nested `panel`.

The structure of the app has a main view which is a tab panel.  One of the items in the tab panel is a defined panel, `xtype: 'homepanel'`.

An item in this panel is the list `xtype: 'newslist'` that is linked to the appropriate store and model files.

The list does not display **unless** I change its parent `homepanel` to a type, `Ext.navigation.View`.

What am I missing in the definition of `homepanel`' as a `panel` that prevents the display of the list?

```
Ext.define('ACSO.view.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel', //<--works if Ext.navigation.View
    xtype: 'homepanel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'ACSO.view.NewsList'
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        cls: 'home',

        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,

        items: [{
            xtype: 'newslist'
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Panel has no layout.

I suggest you try to add the following in your panel config:

```
layout:'fit'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `layout: 'card'` to your panel's config

Answer (score 0):

`Layout: fit` didn't work out for me.
However, adding `layout: 'card` to the parent `Ext.Panel` worked!

The UI component which is within the `Ext.Panel` is no longer hidden via the `display: none !important;`.