# List won't display with proper height with other elements in the view in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: css, listview, height, sencha-touch-2

I have a layout with some content and a list. I have tried various ST2 layouts for the containing element but I cannot get the list to display at all. There is data and I have verified this by forcing the height of the list via developer console. Here's the config code for my view:

```
config: {
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'vbox',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'vbox',
                        cls: 'retailer-detail-container',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                layout: {
                                    type: 'hbox'
                                },
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'img',
                                        cls: 'offerDetailImg',
                                        itemId: 'retailer-detail-image'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'container',
                                        layout: 'vbox',
                                        items: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'vbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                                        cls: 'offer-detail-name',
                                                        itemId: 'retailer-detail-name'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                                        cls: 'offer-detail-distance',
                                                        itemId: 'retailer-detail-distance'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                cls: 'offer-detail-actions',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'button',
                                                        cls: 'retailer-detail-contact-button',
                                                        itemId: 'retailer-detail-contact-button'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'button',
                                                        cls: 'retailer-detail-map-button',
                                                        itemId: 'retailer-detail-map-button'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                cls: 'offer-detail-description',
                                itemId: 'retailer-detail-description'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                                xtype: 'list',
                                itemId: 'retailerOffersList',
                                scrollable: 'true',
                                ui: 'round',
                                itemTpl: '<strong>{offer_title}</strong>',
                                onItemDisclosure: true
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions on SO about this already, have you tried some of their answers? My first suggestion would be to play with the `layout` property of the immediate parent of the list:

```
layout:'fit'
```

- [Sencha Touch 2: List does not display in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820016/sencha-touch-2-list-does-not-display-in-panel)
- [Sencha Touch 2 - Can't get list to display // or load a store? [UPDATED X2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334109/sencha-touch-2-cant-get-list-to-display-or-load-a-store-updated-x2)

Comment: I have tried `'fit'` but it doesn't make any difference. I have also tried removing all of the layout properties on all the elements and leaving only 'fit' on the view (container) itself. This has the effect of the list filling the whole view and overlaying the other container. I want both container and list to show on the screen and be scrollable.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I haven't played with having a container and list both visible. I'll try it out and see what I can come up with.